# MIME type for reading CSV file in an Android app does not work

Tags: java, android, csv, mime-types, read-csv

maybe I can get help here. I'm working on an Android app in Java and try to pick a .csv file to import some data:

```
    public void onButtonImportClick(View view) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onButtonImportClick");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("text/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[] { "text/csv", "text/plain" });
        someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
    }
```

The picker shows files but all are greyed out, besides the .txt files. Actually I expected to get .csv and .txt files. Obviously something is not correct with MIME type setting.
Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use **opencsv** for read CSV file.

Add below gradle into `gradle` file.

> implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:4.6'

Implement below function for read csv file

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
int returnValue = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { 
    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file));
    List myEntries = reader.readAll();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but where do I store the yourfile.csv? Ideally it should be in the Download folder of the device. If I do not use a picker, user will not be able to navigate, right?

Comment: @reichi Yes, you have to select file from local storage & give that file to FileReader

Comment: Okay, but the file will not be in the local storage. It will be provided from user in the download folder. I think I need the file picker.